# How to programmatically reference multiple string-array by clicking on list item

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-listview

I am new to android programming and wanna know this,

I have four string-array defined in string.xml file

```
<resources>
<string-array name="person_name">
    <item>Max</item>
    <item>Heven</item>
    <item>Jhon</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="phone">
    <item>123</item>
    <item>456</item>
    <item>789</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="address">
    <item>XYZ</item>
    <item>ABC</item>
    <item>MNO</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="area_code">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
```

I am using listview to show person_name string-array.

Now I want, when I am clicking on person name , I want to show there corresponding phone number, email, address and area code using textview in another activity.

Comment: It's **so easy**. Just pass the position to the next activity. And show the contents from the other arrays at the same index. And no, **I won't** write that code for you. That's left as an `exercise`.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242685/how-to-retrieve-array-of-array-in-listview). Here is my code . Now help me plz... @DerGolem

Comment: Given that Max phone is 123, his area code is 1 and his address is XYZ, then - once you got all the arrays from the resources - all the array items at index 0 belong to Max. All array items at index 1 belong to Heven. And so on.

Comment: yes thats what i want but how???

Comment: I don't get you... once you have your arrays (you know ho to get them, right?) - Simply, `String Max = names[0] + " " + addresses[0] + " " + areas[0] + " " + phones[0];`... what else?

Comment: But i have more then 100 names.......

Comment: Then an array system is not a good idea. A database is (it would also be **searchable**).

Answer (score 0):

Since we are talking about data which has a *relation*, you probably want to use a relational data structure like a relational database. In Android, you can use [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

If you do not expect your data to grow (it will always be the same persons), you could also JSON encode the values and pass the whole string to the next `Activity`

```
<resources>
<string-array name="person">
    <item>{"name": "Max", "phone":"123", "address":"XYZ", "areaCode": "1"}</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should really use a database to store such data.

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

Then get the element number the user clicked on and access this position in `planets`.

See [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray).

Comment: You're right, simply taking the list position works as well.

Comment: Not in the case of the db (you have to use the ids). But for the arrays (which is valid for very little data), it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow some simple steps :

1) Take position of "person_name" when it's click.

2) Pass that position to second activity using intent.

3) Get Values of other string arrays from that position.